# ExecuteQuery will return this error "Item does not exists it might be deleted by another user" on existing item

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I am working on remote event receiver, and i have this code:-

```
Folder folder0 = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/library3/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
context.Load(folder0.ListItemAllFields);
context.ExecuteQuery();
ListItem folderItem0 = folder0.ListItemAllFields;
if (folderItem0["SourceListItemID"].ToString() == listItemID.ToString())
{
Folder folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/library3/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
folder.MoveTo(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
folder.Update();
//code goes here..
ListItem folderItem = folder.ListItemAllFields;
context.Load(folderItem);//this will raise the error
```

so can anyone advice what is wrong with my code?

context.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: If you comment out the last context.load, does the `MoveTo` succeed?

Comment: Did you make a cut and paste mistake?  The path of the folder you are getting inside your conditional is exactly the same as `folder0`.  If that is intentional, you don't need to get the folder again, just use folder0.

Comment: @willman yes i have 2 references to the same folder, as i want to make sure that the second reference is for the moved folder... in all the cases why i am getting an error on my code?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the `MoveTo` on your original reference, then after executing, grab the newly moved folder by its new path.  Trying to perform an operation on a reference that is still pointing to the old location is likely the problem.  Try this:

```
Folder folder0 = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/library3/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
context.Load(folder0.ListItemAllFields);
context.ExecuteQuery();
ListItem folderItem0 = folder0.ListItemAllFields;
if (folderItem0["SourceListItemID"].ToString() == listItemID.ToString())
{
    folder0.MoveTo(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
    folder0.Update();
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    Folder folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
    context.Load(folder);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    //code goes here..
    ListItem folderItem = folder.ListItemAllFields;
    context.Load(folderItem);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Also, since attempting to do any operations on `folder0` after it is moved would likely throw the same error, instead of getting a whole new reference, you can just updated `folder0` to point to the new folder location, like this:

```
Folder folder0 = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/library3/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
context.Load(folder0.ListItemAllFields);
context.ExecuteQuery();
ListItem folderItem0 = folder0.ListItemAllFields;
if (folderItem0["SourceListItemID"].ToString() == listItemID.ToString())
{
    folder0.MoveTo(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
    folder0.Update();
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    folder0 = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/ArchDocs/" + currentFilingSystemItem["DealName"].ToString());
    context.Load(folder0);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    //code goes here..
    ListItem folderItem = folder0.ListItemAllFields;
    context.Load(folderItem);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```